# Other particles with も

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-を, particle-も

Said at the start of the summer holidays:

> 「お役に立てて光栄です。丸尾スエオ**二学期も**がんばりますから、みなさんどうかよろしくいたします」
>   It's an honour to be helpful. Maruo Sueo will do his best in the second term too so thanks for your support everyone.
>   うやうやしく頭を下げた丸尾君のその心は、二学期の学級委員の選挙運動**をも**見据えていた。
>   The mind of Maruo, who was respectfully bowing his head, was focused on the election for class representative for the second term.

In the first part in bold (丸尾スエオ**二学期も**がんばります) I would have expected to see the particle に (丸尾スエオ二学期**にも**がんばります) "Maruo will do his best **in** the second term too. Would this also be correct? If so, why can it be omitted?

In the second part in bold I was surprised to see をも. I thought も always replaced を. What's going on here?

Comment: Related: https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/9481468.html

Comment: While being marginal, 二学期 doesn't need に for the same reason as 明日 or 今日 don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, you can say 二学期は頑張ります, so you can say 二学期も頑張ります, too. You can find lots of existing questions regarding は vs に vs には.

も does not always replace を. The combination をも can be used to strongly emphasize the object it marks. The English equivalent of this をも is "even".

> 彼の拳は岩**をも**砕く。 His fist even breaks a rock.

This をも is relatively literary. すら, まで, or stressed も is usually preferred in conversations.